# Resolving an "Admin" object in admin.py

Tags: django

So, I'm following the example on django-ajax-selects:

http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/

and I have gotten up to the part where we are create the following class in **admin.py**:

```
class ContactMailingAdmin(Admin):
    form = make_ajax_form(ContactMailing,dict(author='contact',contacts='contact'))
```

The problem is that the "Admin" in the parameter list is unable to be resolved and I was wondering if anyone knows what to import to get that to resolve or if it's OK to replace it with admin.ModelAdmin. Basically, how would I go about getting the example listed on the site (linked above) to work. I've tried looking in "django.contrib.auth.admin" and "django.contrib.auth.models" but can't seem to find anything useful.

Thanks in advance for any pointers and help.

I'm relatively new to Django so if I've left out any information or if you need any sort of clarification, please do let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: It might be a typo (or be taken from an example where ModelAdmin is imported as Admin) as this example (https://github.com/millioner/django-ajax-select/blob/master/example/ajax_select_example/admin.py) is using the regular admin.ModelAdmin you mentioned. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Admin` class in `django-select` and I see in their [admin.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/source/browse/trunk/ajax_select/admin.py) that they are using `django.contrib.auth.admin.ModelAdmin`

--> it's a typo and you can use `django.contrib.auth.admin.ModelAdmin`.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for your reply.

I also didn't know about their repository on GitHub so I definitely thank you for that since having a working example would make understanding this much easier!

Answer (score 0):

First have a look at [ModelAdmin objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects). Try to do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ContactMailingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = make_ajax_form(ContactMailing,dict(author='contact',contacts='contact'))
```